# Does having about 100 sites with apache dramatically slow down response time compared to having just one or two?

Tags: unix, webserver

Does having about 100 sites with apache dramatically slow down response time compared to having just one or two?

my vhosts.conf is huge

**Edit:** no, i mean purely the part of apache that reads through the vhosts.conf file and finds the record for the domain, and what user/where its "folder" is. i don't mean bandwidth etc. just does having 100+ sites mean it takes considerably longer (ie, would it have an impact on a server doing 60-70k uniques a day) than just having 1 record in the vhosts.conf

(btw, when i talk about vhosts, that is how my server deals with having multiple domains on one server. i don't know if this is normal but from a google it looks like it is)

Comment: Since it seems obvious that accessing 100 sites costs more than when only one is accessed, little question: do you mean in similar usage ? That if only one website is accessed, does it matter if there is only one, or 100 managed by apache ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple matter of throughput:

If 100 sites require a 100 times more bandwidth, then, yes, things will slow down until you upgrade your equipment and/or your line.

Equipment means here : number of physical server computers and their components, hard disks, network cards, router.